# how to create Dynamic pickers inside loop in react-native?

Tags: react-native

This is my steps:

The Json code:

```
"features": [
            {
                "name": "size",
                "selected": null,
                "values": [
                    {
                        "value": "40",
                        "label": "40",
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "41",
                        "label": "41",
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "color",
                "selected": "gray",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "value": "gray",
                        "label": "gray"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "black",
                        "label": "black",
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

Step2: define state

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state ={selectedDropDownValue:[]};
}
```

step3:

main render:

```
render{
    return(
        {this.printPickers()}
    );
}
```

and

```
printPickers(){

    const listItems = data.map((obj,index) =>

        <Item picker key={'mykey1' + index}>
            <Picker
                selectedValue={(this.state.selectedDropDownValue[obj.label]) ?this.state.selectedDropDownValue[obj.label] : obj.selected}
                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex, itemName) =>this.pickerChange(itemIndex,itemValue,obj.name)}
                >
                {
                    obj1.values.map( (v)=>{
                        return <Picker.Item key={'mykey2' + index} label={v.label} value={v.value} />
                    })
                }
            </Picker>
        </Item>

    );
    return (<View>{listItems}</View>);
  }
```

and finally:

```
pickerChange(itemIndex,itemValue,itemName){

      this.setState({
          selectedDropDownValue: Object.assign(this.state.selectedDropDownValue, {[itemName]: itemValue})
      });

  }
```

My problem I can not change options of each pickers by touching them but with `console.log(this.state.selectedDropDownValue)`, I get right data.

My problem I can not change options of each pickers by touching them but with `console.log(this.state.selectedDropDownValue)`, I get right data.

Answer (score 0):

There is some mismatch in json data. Either both should have a key **label** or **name**.

So suppose both items have key as **label** then you need to update your pickerChange function call like this:

```
this.pickerChange(itemIndex,itemValue,obj.label)
```